# Compiling UWP in Release mode return error ILT0040: Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract' was not found

Tags: uwp, .net-core

I try to compile a VS2015 solution containing a UWP project with no success so far:
I always get the following error if I try to build the Release version (Debug works):

> ILT0040: Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract' was not
>   found. Check that your build system references Windows.winmd,
>   references .NET for Windows Store Apps, and is configured to use .NET
>   Native.

I tried it with installing different version of .NET Core Runtimes (Windows Software Development Kit 10.0.10.586, etc..), different versions of VS 2015 (Update 1, 2 and 3) on different versions of Windows 10 (also v1511), but I always get the same error.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue for a new UWP project? If not, could you remove your business data to create a demo?

Comment: I am getting the same issue when compiling from a VSTS build agent on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM with all VS2015 updates and UWP SDK installed.